# Websites doesn't work within android google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

My problem is that I can't surf websites on the server I manage from within the Android Google Chrome browser.

All the websites on the server give me an error:

> this site can't be reached
>   ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

but if I try a different browser other than chrome, it works.

The server has WHM/Cpanel installed and is running Apache 2.4. The websites are on hosted on cloudflare and consist of private PHP programming scripts.

What could be the reason of the this problem?

Comment: I reformulated the question for (hopefully) better understanding.

Comment: many thanks & sorry for bothering